JetBrains plugin: can't get rid of tab group when last tab closes
I'm trying to put together my first plugin for JetBrains (for now for my own use so it doesn't have to be perfect).
I'm trying to make an action that, when user closes a tab, will simultaneously close all other tabs for the same file that might be open as a result of splitting.
Unfortunately, even though there is a param responsible for closing all copies:
editorManagerImpl.closeFile(currentFile, true, true);

I'm not getting the expected result.
Assume, You open file1, then file2, and then split-open file2 two more times. I end up with 3 tab groups:
file1, file2 | file2 | file2

then I issue my command against file2 and the result is:
all instances of file2 close, indeed, but I remain with three groups, each filled with file1
file1 | file1 | file1

I would expect to end up with just one tab group containing file1
file1

I don't see a reason why file1 would clone over the groups. What is the correct way of closing a tab group when its last tab closes?
public class CloseTabWithSplitCopiesAction extends AnAction {
    @Override
    public @NotNull ActionUpdateThread getActionUpdateThread() {
        return ActionUpdateThread.EDT;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(@NotNull AnActionEvent e) {
        Project project = e.getProject();
        if (project == null) return;

        VirtualFile currentFile = e.getData(CommonDataKeys.VIRTUAL_FILE);
        if (currentFile == null) return;

        FileEditorManager editorManager = FileEditorManager.getInstance(project);
        if (editorManager instanceof FileEditorManagerImpl) {
            FileEditorManagerImpl editorManagerImpl = (FileEditorManagerImpl) editorManager;
            editorManagerImpl.closeFile(currentFile, true, true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(@NotNull AnActionEvent e) {
        Project project = e.getProject();
        VirtualFile file = e.getData(CommonDataKeys.VIRTUAL_FILE);
        e.getPresentation().setEnabledAndVisible(project != null && file != null);
    }
}

